# Install e. without compiling c files

Tags: pip, cython, conda

Due to different gcc versions on different servers,
would like to do install

```
   git clone myrepo
   cd subproject
   pip install e.   --no-compile-c-files
```

Since I have already compiled c files on dev. server.
Thanks

How can I specify not to compile the c files ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already compiled *.c files on dev. server you should create a wheel distribution on that server with command

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Distribute that wheel and install it instead of installing from sources.